# Make telephone call from Windows Store App C# WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, phone-call

I am developing a Windows Store App using WinRT in C#.

I want to create a button or a link that the user can click/tap, and the device's default app to make phone calls is used.

Better still, if the user could choose the app to use (if more than one is installed), that would be good, too.

---

I am looking for a similar behaviour to how you can click a `tel://01234567890` link from a web browser, and the browser hands this off to the phone/device so the user can call it.

With that in mind -

- On phones it tends to be the phone app, or an option to choose if there is more than one app that can make calls
- On PCs where an app is installed that can make calls (e.g. Skype), clicking a `tel://` link tends to open it by default through that (browser usually asks beforehand)

---

Searching around I have found everything for Windows Phone 8.1 so far. But nothing for Windows Store Apps using Windows RunTime in Win 8/8.1.

**Please note:** I am not *specifically* looking to make the call from *within* the app, more so to open the default app the device uses. However, I am open to options, so if there is also a way to do it from within the app, I would consider that, too.

---

Is this possible? Is there an API or Library that I might need?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution to get the described behaviour as in the question.

I used the same `tel://` "link" concept as I was talking about in my question.

The solution I came up with:

- create a URI
- launch it from the app
- the device then handles opening the URI; asking which app to use if necessary

---

This was as simple as one line:

```
private async Task MakePhoneCall(string phoneNumber)
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri($"tel://{phoneNumber}"));
}
```

The `Launcher`  static class is found in the `Windows.System` namespace (`using Windows.System;`).

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

@Geoff have a Good answer and I have another.

You can use the PhoneCallManager to call when device is mobile and use Skype to call when device is pc.

If the device is mobile and you can use the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI` to call the number.And it's checked the device is mobile.

```
if (Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Mobile")
{
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager
           .ShowPhoneCallUI("The number you call",
                            "The pople's name that is the number ower");
}
```

It's like that [image]
<sub>(source: [9uads.com](http://jycloud.9uads.com/web/GetObject.aspx?filekey=c0df6586a5d486d0ce7cd9447fd75f59))</sub>

When you use it,you should include `Windows Mobile Extensions`

[image]

And if your device is pc,you also can use the Skype to call.

```
private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   
{
    Uri url=new Uri(@"Skype:number?call");
    var areSkypeCall = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(url);
    if (areSkypeCall)
    {
        //Success
    }
}
```

The format of Uri is "Skype:"+number+"?call" or "Skype:"+skype id+"?call".

[image]

See [UWP use skype to call number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777603/uwp-use-skype-to-call-number)

Comment: Hi @lindexi - thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this is a Store App for Windows Runtime, not for Windows Phone 8/8.1 like I mentioned in my question, so I won't be able to use your suggestion about the `PhoneCallManager`. As regarding using the `Launcher` class, I'd rather not be tied to just using Skype if possible - just in case there are alternative apps that can make calls, also. The app is currently being migrated to the UWP, so I will bear your link to using Skype on UWP in mind. Thank you again for your effort :)

Comment: Sorry for cant help you.I see the win8.1 app as uwp,and there is my error.